# Need to convert array using 2 array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays like below

```
Array1 = Array(
            [8756] => 1A10
            [8758] => 1B20
            [8770] => 1B25
        )

Array2 = Array(
            [8756] => 413072-FT6
            [8758] => 413072-HT4
            [8770] => 413072-WT4
        )
```

Above both array have the same key and diff value I need the new array which have the structure like below

```
Array
(
    [8756] => Array
        (
            [loc] => 1A10
            [sku] => 413072-FT6
        )

    [8758] => Array
        (
            [loc] => 1B20
            [sku] => 413072-HT4
        )

    [8770] => Array
        (
            [loc] => 1B25
            [sku] => 413072-WT4
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this working? Seeing your attempts might help us understand your problem.

Comment: I have sort 2 array seperately and now I need to combine with same key and need to pass the array like this

Comment: So again - you tried nothing?

Comment: is it possible or not. I have done some R&D and tried some tricks but didn't get any solution

Comment: @Ch037 everything is possible when you try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop and then grab the right parts

```
$locs = //your array1;
$skus = //your array2;
$merged = array(); //what to add it to
foreach($locs as $key => $value){ //need key to place in merged and grab from skus
    $merged[$key]['loc'] = $value;
    $merged[$key]['sku'] = $skus[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 $ar1 = array( "8756" => "1A10",
            "8758" => "1B20",
            "8770" => "1B25");
$ar2 = array(
"8756" => "413072-FT6",
            "8758" => "413072-HT4",
            "8770" => "413072-WT4"
);
$newarr = array();
foreach($ar1 as $k=>$v){
    array_push($newarr, $newarr[$k]=array('loc'=>$v, 'sku'=>$ar2[$k]));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$new_array = array();
$Array1 = Array(
           '8756' => '1A10',
           '8758' =>' 1B20',
           '8770' =>' 1B25',
        );

$Array2 = Array(
           '8756' => '413072-FT6',
           '8758' => '413072-HT4',
            '8770' => '413072-WT4',
        );


foreach( $Array1 as $key => $_val) 
{ 
    $new_array[$key]['loc'] =  $_val;
    $new_array[$key]['sku'] = $Array2[$key];
}


print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Array
   (
   [8756] => Array
    (
        [loc] => 1A10
        [sku] => 413072-FT6
    )

[8758] => Array
    (
        [loc] =>  1B20
        [sku] => 413072-HT4
    )

[8770] => Array
    (
        [loc] =>  1B25
        [sku] => 413072-WT4
    )
)
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/nE7S4)**